# Babel/JSX Transpiler error on build when importing a module into new create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs, create-react-app, unexpected-token

React Noob here.

I have been stuck on this for a little while.

I have tried to add a module into a project I'm making, but found the same problem occurs when I run it with a new create-react-app.

I believe it is related to babel/JSX, because if I put the imported modules src into a fresh project or just into the src of the existing one it seems to compile fine, just not as an import.

1) set up new react app:

```
npx create-react-app test-project
cd test-project
```

2) install package:

```
npm install --save react-collision-provider
```

3) Add an import to the App.js

```
+ import { collisionProviderFactory } from 'react-collision-provider';
```

4) start project

```
npm start
```

Error:

```
./node_modules/react-collision-provider/src/components/collisionProviderFactory.js
SyntaxError: /Users/XXXXXXX/Documents/TestProjects/test-project/node_modules/react-collision-provider/src/components/collisionProviderFactory.js: Unexpected token (37:14)

  35 |     render() {
  36 |       const Component = this.props.component;
> 37 |       return (<Component
     |               ^
  38 |         onCollision={this.onCollision}
  39 |         updatePosition={this.updatePosition}
  40 |         {...this.props}
```

I have tried to mess around with different babel settings and ejecting the project but no luck. I heard CRA doesn't transpile node_modules only src, but not sure how to compile the JSX in advanced in the node_modules?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, the issue is that the `react-collision-provider` hasn't been *properly transpiled to be understood by the browser*. The **browser doesn't naturally understand `JSX`** as this is syntactic sugar to easily create your `React` component views. This is why we use `babel` to transform `JSX` into `React.createElement(...);` calls which is native `JavaScript` and can be understood by the browser.

Perhaps you could do the following:

1. Download `babel-cli`:

   `npm install --save-dev @babel/cli`
2. Download `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx` plugin. We need this plugin since `Babel` 6 and up *no longer have any native transforms for React*. This is necessary to transpile unsupported `JavaScript` features, such as `JSX`, into native `JavaScript` which can be understood by the browser.

   `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx`
3. Create a custom command within the `scripts` section of your `package.json` file to tranpile your `react-collision-provider` node module. Something like the following:

   `"scripts": {
        ...
       "libTranspile": "babel --plugins @babel/transform-react-jsx <path_to_react_collison_module> --out-dir <path_to_react_collision_module> --copy-files",
       ...
     },`
4. Now you should be able to run your custom command to transpile your `react-collision-provider` module:

   `npm run libTranspile`

The `react-collision-provider` module should now be transpiled, with all the `JSX` code sections replaced with `React.createElement(...);` calls.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: That looks like it makes sense thanks! Will test out and let you know how it goes. Ideally I'd like a solution where I can just list my imported modules by name that might need transpiling (perhaps remembering if they have been since last edit or not), or better yet a command to transpile when installing in the first place "npm i --save --transpile package_name". I will have a think and update my post if I find a leaner solution :)

Comment: You could potentially eject and add that node_module within your webpack.config.js entry point so it can be transpiled with babel. For your latter statement you would need to create a custom script